# Accessing Twitter tweet comments

Tags: twitter

There are ways to get the user timeline tweets from twitter pages. I was wondering if the comments to the tweets was also accessible. I am trying to do sentiment analysis to various posts/tweets along with the comments. I am using the tweepy.API().user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200) for extracting the tweets. Is there a way to get the comments to the tweets as well? I am using Python for programming.

Comment: What do you mean by "comments to the tweets"? Could you give an example?

Comment: @TerenceEden For instance I have to extract all the tweets from https://twitter.com/NBCOlympics. For tweet https://twitter.com/NBCOlympics/status/759820743915954176, there are many comments/opinion to the tweet ( https://twitter.com/sea77king/status/759826305986678784 is one of them). I have to take these comments/opinions as well. Hope I am clear.

Comment: Ah! You mean "Replies".  There is currently no way to get replies to a Tweet via the API.